# How to make a button fit into an upvote icon

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a button that has the shape of an icon but the button overflows the icon

```css
.upvote, .downvote {
            font-size: 55px;
        }

        .up {
            color: green;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

   <button class="upvote up"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
   <a class="upvote up"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
```

It works fine for `a` tag but I want to use it in a submit form so I can't use `a` tag.

Comment: Hi, so basically you are trying to create a button in the shape of `upvote`, right? The button cannot be fit into the icon, as per your code. Because the icon was wrapped inside button, and you are trying to do the opposite

Comment: I tried doing the opposite button it didn't work @AbinThaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an icon inside the button, you can follow this method. Here I have modified the button matching the styles of the icon. This way you can keep the properties of a button, while having a different design.

Otherwise, you can add a clickEventListener to the icon itself as Simone's answer

```css
.arrow-up {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
}
```

```html
<button class='arrow-up'></button>
```

Please find the same for arrow-down

```css
.arrow-down {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid green;
}
```

```html
<button class='arrow-down'></button>
```

This way you can completely avoid the usage of fa icons if this is your only requirement.

Comment: why did you remove the second snippet ?

Comment: I was editing it. try this now. I can workout the class for `arrow-down` too

Comment: Can you add the class for arrow-down ?

Comment: I just did, can you check? If you want both, just add a common class and move all the styles except the `border-bottom` for arrow-up and `border-top` for 'arrow-down. So code will be clean.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use directly the icon as button like:

```css
.upvote,
.downvote {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.up {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-5x upvote up"></i>
```

i add `fa-5x` for the size and `cursor: pointer;` for cursor in hover state.

---

Into a form:

```js
const myform = document.getElementById('myform');
document.querySelector('.up').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myform.submit();
});
```

```css
.upvote,
.downvote {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.up {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form id='myform'>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-5x upvote up"></i>
</form>
```

---

Else you can use SVG sprites [Link official](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-sprites), i can't post an example for Same origin policy

Comment: because I need the icon clickable inside a form

Comment: i add an example with `addEventListener` into a form and svg alternative.

Comment: i change it to submit event (js solution)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the margin and padding of the icon as well as the button and also define height and width by yourself.

```
.upvote, .downvote {
            margin: 0px;
            padding:0px;
            font-size: 55px;
        }

        .up {
            margin: 0px;
            padding:0px;
            height:..;
            color: green;
        }
```